# C++ classes hierarchy => to XSD schema? Anyone know tool or example?

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, schema

I know that I could convert XSD schema to C++ classes using codesynthesis mechanism.
What about vice versa?

Lets say I have a very difficult class hierarchy in C++ and I would like to get XSD schema, so I could use it by any other language in future?

Comment: What do you mean? C++ classes can be very complex compared to what CodeSynthesis' product might output. Are you interested in class fields, member functions, only member functions which look like getters and setters, or what?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about any ready-made tool but [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) provides an interface to the AST produced from C++ sources. It would be possible to create suitable tool on the basis of this this AST.

There is also [gccxml](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html) which represents, at least, the declarations found in a C++ using XML. However, I haven't used gccxml and I don't know if it is still maintained.